# Swift unity raycast equivalent

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I want to check if there is an object below my player in my endless 3D runner, something like ray casting in unity. Is there a equivalent or does someone know how to do it differently maybe?

Checking for collision I tried but since it's a ball, making it have a dynamic physics body makes it go all over the place.

Comment: I use SceneKit if that is what you mean. The scene itself is managed in a coaco touch class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SCNNode` exposes `-hitTestWithSegmentFromPoint:toPoint:options:`.

In the [Fox: Building a SceneKit Game with the Xcode Scene Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Fox) sample obstacles and the ground are static physics bodies and `-[SCNPhysicsWorld rayTestWithSegmentFromPoint:toPoint:options:]` is used to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: I Will look into it! Thank you very much!